# What is the best way to create text button with background image in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to have a text over an image solution - any suggestions pls?

I'd like to use Html helper:

```
$this->Html->link
```

Comment: Please consider improving your question. Your question in its current form does not contain enough details. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section on ways to improve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.link-bg {
    background:url(../img/nav.png) no-repeat;
    width:auto;
    display:block;
    padding:10px 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    /*text-indent: -999em;  uncomment if you want to hide the
    text but keep it (e.g screen readers */
}

echo $this->Html->link('Link Text', array('controller'=>'foo', 
                                          'action'=>'bar'),
                                    array('title'=>'Link Text',
                                          'class'=>'link-bg')
                      );
```

Given your requirements aren't clear, this may or may not work as you intend.
Essentially `link` takes a 3rd parameter- an array of `$options` such as `class`.